# Check if <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy> object is empty

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm downloading some data from a SQL Server database through a library that leverages `pymssql` in the back-end. The result of a `curson.execute("""<QUERY BODY>""")` is a `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy` object. How can I check if the result of the query was empty, so there are no rows?

```
cur = ff.sql.create_engine(server=dw.address, db=dw.BI_DW,
                               login=":".join([os.environ["SQL_USER"],
                                               os.environ["SQL_PASSWD"]]))
for n in range(100):
    result = cur.execute("""QUERY BODY;""")
    if result:
        break
```

Unfortunately, `result` will never be `None` even when no rows were returned by the SQL query.

What's the best way to check for that?

Comment: Can you provide the text of your query? If the only thing you need to do is check whether the amount of fetched rows is zero than there are probably more effective ways to achieve this.

Comment: The query body is not important. The issue I'm having is that the table in SQL wasn't partitioned with yesterday data, thus didn't return any row. What I need to implement is some logic in my script that understand whether the amount of fetched rows is zero.

Comment: Why can't you just use `COUNT(*)` in your query?

Comment: The for loop is a (admittedly stupid) way to keep querying the database until I get some results. I'm going to refactor that.

Comment: I don't like the solution of counting the number of rows, because this means I need to run two queries. One to count the number of rows and in case stop the program, and the second one to fetch the results that I'll then process one row at the time.

Comment: The thing about `ResultProxy` is that you can't know the amount of returned rows until you fetch all of them either one by one through iteration, or all at once through `.fetchall()` method.

Answer (score 10):

The `ResultProxy` object does not contain any rows yet. Therefore it has no information about the total amount of them, or even whether there are any. `ResultProxy` is just a "pointer" to the database. You get your rows only when you explicitly fetch them via `ResultProxy`. You can do that via iteration over this object, or via `.first()` method, or via `.fetchall()` method.

**Bottom line**: you cannot know the amount of fethced rows until you actually fetch all of them and the `ResultProxy` object is exhausted.

## Approach #1

You can fetch all the rows at once and count them and then do whatever you need with them:

```
rows = result.fetchall()
if len(rows):
    # do something with rows
```

The downside of this method is that we load all rows into memory at once (`rows` is a Python `list` containing all the fetched rows). This may not be desirable if the amount of fetched rows is very large and/or if you only need to iterate over the rows one-by-one independently (usually that's the case).

## Approach #2

If loading all fetched rows into memory at once is not acceptable, then we can do this:

```
rows_amount = 0
for row in result:
    rows_amount += 1
    # do something with row
if not rows_amount:
    print('There were zero rows')
else:
    print('{} rows were fetched and processed'.format(rows_amount))
```

Comment: I didn't even think about `first()`. However, I do need to process those rows after this check, so this solution won't work for me.

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

I followed your comment fetchone() fetchall nothing

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy < 1.2: You can always turn the ResultProxy into an iterator:

```
res = engine.execute(...)
rp_iter = iter(res)
row_count = 0
try:
    row = next(rp_iter)
    row_count += 1
except StopIteration:
    # end of data
    if not row_count:
      # no rows returned, StopIteration was raised on first attempt
```

In [SQLAlchemy >= 1.2, the ResultProxy implements both `.next()` and `.__next__()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.next), so you do not need to create the iterator:

```
res = engine.execute()
row_count = 0
try:
    row = next(res)
    row_count += 1
except StopIteration:
    ...
```